# Compiling goldfish kernel Kconfig causing issues

Tags: android, compiler-errors, cygwin

Running Windows 7 with latest version of Cygwin with literally every option installed, trying to compile the Android goldfish kernel 3.10. I was having a major headache that turned out to be caused by git checking out the repo with Windows file endings, but now that I have that sorted out, it looks like it's not parsing the /usr/Kconfig file properly for some reason.

```
make ARCH=arm SUBARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi- goldfish_armv7_defconfig
usr/Kconfig:18: syntax error
usr/Kconfig:17: unknown option "When"
usr/Kconfig:18: unknown option "initramfs"
usr/Kconfig:21: syntax error
usr/Kconfig:20: unknown option "See"
usr/Kconfig:23: syntax error
usr/Kconfig:22: unknown option "If"
usr/Kconfig:35: syntax error
usr/Kconfig:34: unknown option "If"
usr/Kconfig:47: syntax error
usr/Kconfig:46: unknown option "If"
usr/Kconfig:104: syntax error
usr/Kconfig:103: unknown option "If"
usr/Kconfig:104: unknown option "initramfs"
usr/Kconfig:107: syntax error
usr/Kconfig:106: unknown option "High"
usr/Kconfig:107: unknown option "low"
usr/Kconfig:108: unknown option "boot"
usr/Kconfig:111: syntax error
usr/Kconfig:110: unknown option "If"
make[1]: *** [/{repo location}/scripts/kconfig/Makefile:105: goldfish_armv7_defconfig] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:504: goldfish_armv7_defconfig] Error 2
```

I tried editing the Kconfig file to remove all of the help text that was throwing the syntax errors, but that still gives "unknown option" errors. Do I need to change some of the make options? I'm really not a *nix or kernel person, so I'm really out of my depth here. I'm just working on trying to get a ROM (Cyanogenmod) running on my emulator for testing purposes and hoping this path will get me there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran dos2unix on the /usr/Kconfig file and it fixed the problem. File endings. Gah.